# Australian drivers licence valid in the US?

Tags: usa, driving, driving-licenses, australian-citizens

I've been trying to find out whether I can rent a car in the US (4-5 days) using only my Australian drivers licence, but my Google foo is failing me. Can anyone enlighten me? Do I still need the international drivers licence piece of paper or can I use an Aussie licence as is?

Comment: I know for sure that a US license can be used in Australia and most countries have a reciprocity agreement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the US Embassy in Australia:

http://canberra.usembassy.gov/resources/all-faqs/travel.html#license

> An International Driving Permit serves as proof of validation of your
>   Australian state license and as another form of photo identification.
>   However, you must also carry your Australian state license. Some
>   rental car agencies require an international driver’s license as part
>   of the agreement.

So legally, you don't need an international permit, but bureaucratically, potentially you may, depending on the company.

I got my international one in NZ, it doesn't cost much, so I'd just go ahead and get it - at least you'll have peace of mind.

Answer (score 9):

I'm an Aussie and have hired cars in the U.S. without having an international driver's license without any trouble. I was barely 21 at the time and I was told that I wouldn't have been able to hire it if I was any younger but the Australian license wasn't an issue at all.

That being said, the international drivers license is really easy to get (I got mine from a RACQ branch in Qld) and might just help you out.

Comment: thanks for that, i just wish i could mark multiple answers as answers

Answer (score 6):

I hired rental cars in the US in 1990 and 2001 with just my Australian photo licence. In 1990 I had an international licence but was told it wasn't necessary when my normal licence already had my photo. I can't say how different these "de facto" rules differ from the official rules.