# Is a European Union (Slovakia) driver's licence valid in the US?

Tags: usa, automobiles, driving-licenses, eu-citizens

I'm leaving for US shortly after I get my drivers licence in 2 weeks or so.

I'm wondering if I'll be able to use it in USA. I know about the AAA thing for US drivers licence to be valid in Slovakia, but I'm not sure how it works the other way around.

Comment: What language(s) is your drivers license in? I believe a big thing about whether your license is valid *on its own* is what language it's written in

Comment: Formally, it could depend on bilateral agreements *and the rules in each individual US state* so I am not sure there is a general answer valid for all EU countries and for the whole of the US. Members on some forums I read strongly suggest getting an International Driving Permit, especially if your license is not in English, not necessarily because it is not valid but because it's quite useful to avoid hassle when dealing with law enforcement officers. I don't have personal experience or sources to back that up so I am posting it as a comment.

Comment: The US consulate/embassy in your country, your ministry of foreign affairs or your country's embassy in the US might be able to provide more information (some have very useful websites, I don't know for Slovakia).

Comment: Related Question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/australian-drivers-licence-valid-in-the-us?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of a foreign license is permitted in any state as long as the license can be read by the police officers. e.g. your name and licence number etc do not include any characters outside the ASCII character set.

As far as length of use is concerned it varies from state to state but usually 30 days is permitted with no issues.  Other than that you can obtain an International Driving Permit, which will solve your problem.

You can check this related question for additional information:

> [Australian drivers licence valid in the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/australian-drivers-licence-valid-in-the-us?rq=1)

Comment: An International Driving Permit (such as those issued by AAA) is *not* a license, however, most states will accept it *in conjunction with* an actual physical license from another country that is not printed in English. It essentially acts as a translation document. Which can be good to have.

Answer (score 2):

If you're renting a car, yes it is valid.

If you buy a car, you'll need to get a valid licence fairly quickly - usually for the insurance company.

Comment: How about if I borrow a car, would I be able to drive it and the cops wouldn't give me hard time? I'll be staying for one month.

Comment: I think insurance might be the bigger issue. If you're insured, I think you're OK.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Buying the car is not an issue.  Registering it is.

Comment: By ***valid*** you mean the OP's license won't be??